# Need help getting Quad to display in front of Sprite in Unity3D 5

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a Quad as a child to a GameObject in my 2D game to create a scrolling sky. I added a script to the Quad and put the following code in the Start

```
var mr = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sortingLayerName = "Foreground";
```

The sprites are on the Background sorting layer.
I tried putting the Quad on the UI layer to see if that would help but it doesn't change anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: is this the new UI system or old UI system

Comment: Is the order of the Sorting Layers in Tags & Layers settings correct?  If so, try changing the Quad's z position.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out my texture changed its type to a normal map. Once I changed it back and selected Unlit/Transparent for the Shader, everything started working.